# How to identify the version number of SQL Server 2008 Standard

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a SQL Server 2008 Standard version and done some service pack upgrade before by some one else. 
When I check the info with select @@version I got following:

Microsoft SQL Server 2008 (SP3) - 10.0.5512.0 (X64)   Aug 22 2012 19:25:47   Copyright (c) 1988-2008 Microsoft Corporation  Standard Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.0  (Build 6002: Service Pack 2)

Confused. Does it means the latest service pack patched with SP2 or SP3?

On another windows 8 server, I have similar info like:

Microsoft SQL Server 2008 (SP1) - 10.0.2531.0 (X64)   Mar 29 2009 10:11:52   Copyright (c) 1988-2008 Microsoft Corporation  Standard Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.0  (Build 6002: Service Pack 2)

Does it means the latest service pack patched with SP1 or SP2?
How to identity the latest service pack installed for SQL server?

Comment: The "Service Pack 2" is the SP of the OS in both those examples.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Head over to http://sqlserverbuilds.blogspot.com/

and check. Build 10.0.5512 is... a tad before SP3... basically a security release before i, in builds.

10.0.2531.0 is Sp1.

This website is where you can look up exact id's.

New releases are announced at

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlreleaseservices/

Comment: If anyone works with SQL, the sites that TomTom has noted above should be book marked.  They're excellent resources for you SQL-types.

Comment: They are baseline - there are ton of releases out and you pretty much need them. I wish they would offer a email release service ;) Can not live without them ;)